# Add a user with full control rights on multiple site collections from one import csv

Tags: powershell, site-collection, web-application, access

I have aa Excel sheet which have multiple site collection sites (around 600) of same web application.
I want to add a user with full control rights on all the site collections from Excel sheet.

My Excel sheet example:

```
http://example.com/aa/bb
http://example.com/cc/dd
```

Please suggest how can I automate it with PowerShell script or by using C# code.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for **SharePoint Online**, then the easiest and only CSOM-free way would be

```
foreach($site in $sites){set-spouser -Site $site -LoginName user@domain.com -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true}
```

Admin is not the same as Full Control, but does not require CSOM.

If this is **SharePoint on prem**, then use this:

```
$csv=import-csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\stack.csv
foreach($site in $csv){Set-SPUser -Identity 'i:0#.w|spo\devuser' -Web $site.Site -AddPermissionLevel "Full Control"}
```

Documentation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607827.aspx